# Can't understand this method tutorial on RubyMonk

Tags: ruby, methods

I'm currently going through the exercises on rubymonk.com, but just can't get my head around this problem.

I'm meant to write three methods, add, subtract and calculate. Calculate is a method combining the add and subtract methods depending on the last argument passed to the method, which should be a hash containing the symbol ':add' or ':subtract'

This is the solution code:

```
def add(*numbers)
    numbers.inject(0) { |sum, number| sum + number }  
end

def subtract(*numbers)
  sum = numbers.shift
  numbers.inject(sum) { |sum, number| sum - number }  
end

def calculate(*arguments)
  # if the last argument is a Hash, extract it 
  # otherwise create an empty Hash
  options = arguments[-1].is_a?(Hash) ? arguments.pop : {}
  options[:add] = true if options.empty?
  return add(*arguments) if options[:add]
  return subtract(*arguments) if options[:subtract]
end
```

I understand everything but this line:

```
  options = arguments[-1].is_a?(Hash) ? arguments.pop : {}
```

Even then, I understand what is occurring, but I don't understand why there's a second '?' or why ': {}' is there. Could anyone explain to me what's going on here?

Thanks!

Comment: Nowadays one would write `def subtract(*numbers); numbers.inject(&:-);
end` .The `sum=numbers.shift` is done by the inject method: when no  initial value is specified, then the first element of collection is used as the initial value of memo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a ternary logic operator.

The format is:

```
<expression to evaluate> ? <result if expression> : <result if !expression>
```

So in your case, the operator is a shorthand for:

```
if arguments[-1].is_a?(Hash)
  arguments.pop
else
  {}
end
```

Also, {} is a constructor for an empty Hash object - this is a guard clause to ensure that `options` will not be `nil` after the assignment.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, thanks. I've gone through ternary operators but it was about 2 chapters back and I forgot the syntax completely.
Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

The comment actually explains it. A different way to write it is this:

```
if (arguments[-1].is_a?(Hash)) {
  arguments.pop
}
else {
  {}
}
```

Where arguments[-1] means the last argument.